# What is the most efficient way to implement multiple threads within a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I need help with my Uni assignment that involves threads. In the assignment, I have to implement a program that contains 4 threads, and one of those threads contains another thread. I've made a diagram below to help explain it better:

[image]

What would be the best/efficient way to do this? My prof gave a very limited explanation on threads, and from what I've gathered so far on the web, I would have to implement the Runnable interface, and create 4 classes from within the main program's run() method, which will probably end up in a mess because I still do not fully grasp the concept of threads in Java. If anyone can suggest a resource where I would be able to learn more, please post it here.

Here's an example of my understanding so far:

```
public class MainThread implements Runnable
{
/**
 * The run method from the Runnable interface that
 * executes the entire program.
 */
public void run()
{
    class Controller implements Runnable
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            class MiniWalker implements Runnable
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class ObjectWalker implements Runnable
    {
        public void run ()
        {   
        }
    }

    class GroupWalker implements Runnable
    {
        public void run ()
        {               
        }
    }

    class YearWalker implements Runnable
    {
        public void run ()
        {           
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The heart and core of this assignment.
 */ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    (new Thread(new MainThread ())).start();
}

}
```

Comment: One thing that it is important to realize is that you _don't_ have to define your `Runnable` classes as inner classes just to get threads that can be forked by another thread.

Answer (score 3):

Threads don't contain other threads.  Threads can *control* other threads, but that's entirely different.  Your control diagram does not have to relate directly to your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you read Brian Goetz' "Java Concurrency In Practice" and dig into the concurrency classes under java.util (e.g. Executor).  They'll make your life better than raw threads.

Comment: This is a homework problem.  I suspect the point is to use `Thread`.

Comment: You might be right, but SO is about education.  If the instructor isn't going to tell them something worthwhile, I feel like it's my job to do it for him/her.

Comment: Sure but to learn Java, it is a good thing to learn about `Thread`, even if you end up using the `ExecutorService` stuff in reality.

Comment: JCIP always seems to be the default answer. I suspect for a uni student new to java, it's not a good idea to get into this book. Its a big, complex book and although it's awesome, it may be too much for the new to java student.

Answer (score 0):

The good place to start is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html . It will give you basic understanding of concurrency in java. Without describing what this thread do (why do you need to create them) it is hard to write which choice would be optimal.

It is worth mentioning that you can spawn threads without explicilty coding new class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Concurrent Programming](http://books.google.com/books?id=-x1S4neCSOYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Doug Lee is another good resource (and virtually all of it is free on google books). It is also worth looking at [an ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). Also, [read through the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) they are pretty decent.

It might be worth trying to break up your application into what would essentially be tasks and just throw them into a thread pool.